# Blueprism Read Web Value From Google Chrome Element

Tags: rpa, blueprism

I am using Blueprism to automate a process using Google Chrome. The Website has a Text Area which I have identified. App Modeler can highlight the element. I want to read the Web Value attribute (which looks to populate correctly on the App Modeler) but I am getting an empty output from my read stage. I have tried both the Get Text and Get Attribute(Web Value) options in the read stage.

Comment: Can you share exactly how the "text area" is defined in your HTML? Anecdotally, I've observed some small issues when spying pure `<textarea></textarea>` elements in Chrome even with the latest versions of Blue Prism. I'm curious also to see how your application modeler has the element configured/listed, and what properties are presented in the Attributes pane.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload images but I have three mapped elements. Web Name being "CustomColumn259sr" , Web Element Type being "TEXTAREA" and Match Index being "1". The Web Value Element is correctly seeing what's on the screen at that time, but it's a variable so that's why I want to read this value. Is there any element in particular you'd like to know the value for?